# How do I make a div fluid when resizing the browser window?

Tags: html, css

I am not certain that other questions apparently similar to mine boil down to the same topic.

Please consider this piece of code (the CSS code has been extracted for the `head` section for more clarity):

```
body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
}

#centredArea {
            background-color: red;
            width: 600px;
            margin: auto;
            min-height: 2000px;
            min-width: 500px;
            text-align: right;
}

#container {
            min-width: 396px;
            padding: 1px;
}

#leftPane {
            background-color: yellowgreen;
            width: 20%;
            min-width: 100px;
            float: left;
            height: 1200px;
}

#rightPane {
            background-color: blue;
            width: 79%;
            float: left;
            height: 1200px;
}

#pictArea {
            height: 140px;
            background-color: pink;
            width: 60%;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#mainTxtArea {
            height: 200px;
            min-height: 100px;
            min-width: 200px;
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 80%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding: 12px;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: left;
}


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>home.htm</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="centredArea">CENTRERED AREA
            <div id='container'>
                <div id="leftPane">LEFT PANE</div>
                <div id="rightPane">
                    <div id='pictArea'>PICT AREA</div>
                    <div id='mainTxtArea'>
                        It may not be unnecessary to inform the reader that the following Reflections had their origin in a correspondence between the Author and avery young gentleman at Paris, who did him the honor of desiring his opinion  upon  the  important  transactions  which  then,  and  ever  since,have so much occupied the attention of all men. An answer was written some time in the month of October 1789, but it was kept back uponprudential considerations. That letter is alluded to in the beginning ofthe following sheets. It has been since forwarded to the person to whom it was addressed. The reasons for the delay in sending it were assigned in a short letter to the same gentleman. This produced on his part a new and pressing application for the Author’s sentiments.<p>
                     The Author began a second and more full discussion on the subject.This he had some thoughts of publishing early in the last spring; but, the matter gaining upon him, he found that what he had undertaken not only far exceeded the measure of a letter, but that its importance required rather a more detailed consideration than at that time he had any leisure to bestow upon it. However, having thrown down his first thoughts inthe  form  of  a  letter,  and,  indeed,  when  he  sat  down  to  write,  havingintended it for a private letter, he found it difficult to change the form ofaddress when his sentiments had grown into a greater extent and had received another direction. A different plan, he is sensible, might be more favorable to a commodious division and distribution of his matter.<p>
                    It may not be unnecessary to inform the reader that the following Reflections had their origin in a correspondence between the Author and avery young gentleman at Paris, who did him the honor of desiring his opinion  upon  the  important  transactions  which  then,  and  ever  since,have so much occupied the attention of all men. An answer was written some time in the month of October 1789, but it was kept back uponprudential considerations. That letter is alluded to in the beginning ofthe following sheets. It has been since forwarded to the person to whom it was addressed. The reasons for the delay in sending it were assigned in a short letter to the same gentleman. This produced on his part a new and pressing application for the Author’s sentiments.<p>
                        The Author began a second and more full discussion on the subject.This he had some thoughts of publishing early in the last spring; but, thematter gaining upon him, he found that what he had undertaken not onlyfar exceeded the measure of a letter, but that its importance required rather a more detailed consideration than at that time he had any leisure to bestow upon it. However, having thrown down his first thoughts inthe  form  of  a  letter,  and,  indeed,  when  he  sat  down  to  write,  havingintended it for a private letter, he found it difficult to change the form ofaddress when his sentiments had grown into a greater extent and had received another direction. A different plan, he is sensible, might be more favorable to a commodious division and distribution of his matter.<p>
                        It may not be unnecessary to inform the reader that the following Reflections had their origin in a correspondence between the Author and avery young gentleman at Paris, who did him the honor of desiring his opinion  upon  the  important  transactions  which  then,  and  ever  since,have so much occupied the attention of all men. An answer was written some time in the month of October 1789, but it was kept back uponprudential considerations. That letter is alluded to in the beginning ofthe following sheets. It has been since forwarded to the person to whom it was addressed. The reasons for the delay in sending it were assigned in a short letter to the same gentleman. This produced on his part a new and pressing application for the Author’s sentiments.<p>
                        The Author began a second and more full discussion on the subject.This he had some thoughts of publishing early in the last spring; but, thematter gaining upon him, he found that what he had undertaken not onlyfar exceeded the measure of a letter, but that its importance required rather a more detailed consideration than at that time he had any leisure to bestow upon it. However, having thrown down his first thoughts inthe  form  of  a  letter,  and,  indeed,  when  he  sat  down  to  write,  havingintended it for a private letter, he found it difficult to change the form ofaddress when his sentiments had grown into a greater extent and had received another direction. A different plan, he is sensible, might be more favorable to a commodious division and distribution of his matter.<p>
                        It may not be unnecessary to inform the reader that the following Reflections had their origin in a correspondence between the Author and avery young gentleman at Paris, who did him the honor of desiring his opinion  upon  the  important  transactions  which  then,  and  ever  since,have so much occupied the attention of all men. An answer was written some time in the month of October 1789, but it was kept back uponprudential considerations. That letter is alluded to in the beginning ofthe following sheets. It has been since forwarded to the person to whom it was addressed. The reasons for the delay in sending it were assigned in a short letter to the same gentleman. This produced on his part a new and pressing application for the Author’s sentiments.<p>
                      The Author began a second and more full discussion on the subject.This he had some thoughts of publishing early in the last spring; but, thematter gaining upon him, he found that what he had undertaken not onlyfar exceeded the measure of a letter, but that its importance required rather a more detailed consideration than at that time he had any leisure to bestow upon it. However, having thrown down his first thoughts inthe  form  of  a  letter,  and,  indeed,  when  he  sat  down  to  write,  havingintended it for a private letter, he found it difficult to change the form ofaddress when his sentiments had grown into a greater extent and had received another direction. A different plan, he is sensible, might be more favorable to a commodious division and distribution of his matter.<p>
                    </div>           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BCoustillas/7oxk0fgr/24/
make the 'browser pane' high enough so that you can see the whole  #mainTxtArea (yellow), which has a y-scroll device.

Now, if you reduce vertically the size of the browser window the usual way, the yellow area, instead of adapting to the remaining space, keeps it original height size and gradually gets out of the browser window's graf port.

What is wrong with my css code?

Comment: Please post your code in the question directly. Don't include a link or an image as a primary source of information. Links might break over time and your question would no longer make sense.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe helps you. please check below code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
}

#centredArea {
            background-color: red;
            width: 600px;
            margin: auto;
            min-height: 2000px;
            text-align: right;
            max-width:100%;
}

#container {
            padding: 1px;
}

#leftPane {
            background-color: yellowgreen;
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
            height: 1200px;
}

#rightPane {
            background-color: blue;
            width: 79%;
            float: left;
            height: 1200px;
}

#pictArea {
            height: 140px;
            background-color: pink;
            width: 60%;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#mainTxtArea {
            height: 200px;
            min-height: 100px;
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 80%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding: 12px;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>home.htm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="centredArea">CENTRERED AREA<!-- +++ -->
        <div id='container'>
            <div id="leftPane" class='coteACote'>LEFT PANE</div>
            <div id="rightPane" class='coteACote'>
                <div id='pictArea'>PICT AREA</div>
                <div id='mainTxtArea'>
                    It may not be unnecessary to inform the reader that the following Reflections had their origin in a correspondence between the Author and avery young gentleman at Paris, who did him the honor of desiring his opinion  upon  the  important  transactions  which  then,  and  ever  since,have so much occupied the attention of all men. An answer was written some time in the month of October 1789, but it was kept back uponprudential considerations. That letter is alluded to in the beginning ofthe following sheets. It has been since forwarded to the person to whom it was addressed. The reasons for the delay in sending it were assigned in a short letter to the same gentleman. This produced on his part a new and pressing application for the Author’s sentiments.<p>
                    The Author began a second and more full discussion on the subject.This he had some thoughts of publishing early in the last spring; but, thematter gaining upon him, he found that what he had undertaken not onlyfar exceeded the measure of a letter, but that its importance required rather a more detailed consideration than at that time he had any leisure to bestow upon it. However, having thrown down his first thoughts inthe  form  of  a  letter,  and,  indeed,  when  he  sat  down  to  write,  havingintended it for a private letter, he found it difficult to change the form ofaddress when his sentiments had grown into a greater extent and had received another direction. A different plan, he is sensible, might be more favorable to a commodious division and distribution of his matter.<p>
                    It may not be unnecessary to inform the reader that the following Reflections had their origin in a correspondence between the Author and avery young gentleman at Paris, who did him the honor of desiring his opinion  upon  the  important  transactions  which  then,  and  ever  since,have so much occupied the attention of all men. An answer was written some time in the month of October 1789, but it was kept back uponprudential considerations. That letter is alluded to in the beginning ofthe following sheets. It has been since forwarded to the person to whom it was addressed. The reasons for the delay in sending it were assigned in a short letter to the same gentleman. This produced on his part a new and pressing application for the Author’s sentiments.<p>
                    The Author began a second and more full discussion on the subject.This he had some thoughts of publishing early in the last spring; but, thematter gaining upon him, he found that what he had undertaken not onlyfar exceeded the measure of a letter, but that its importance required rather a more detailed consideration than at that time he had any leisure to bestow upon it. However, having thrown down his first thoughts inthe  form  of  a  letter,  and,  indeed,  when  he  sat  down  to  write,  havingintended it for a private letter, he found it difficult to change the form ofaddress when his sentiments had grown into a greater extent and had received another direction. A different plan, he is sensible, might be more favorable to a commodious division and distribution of his matter.<p>
                    It may not be unnecessary to inform the reader that the following Reflections had their origin in a correspondence between the Author and avery young gentleman at Paris, who did him the honor of desiring his opinion  upon  the  important  transactions  which  then,  and  ever  since,have so much occupied the attention of all men. An answer was written some time in the month of October 1789, but it was kept back uponprudential considerations. That letter is alluded to in the beginning ofthe following sheets. It has been since forwarded to the person to whom it was addressed. The reasons for the delay in sending it were assigned in a short letter to the same gentleman. This produced on his part a new and pressing application for the Author’s sentiments.<p>
                    The Author began a second and more full discussion on the subject.This he had some thoughts of publishing early in the last spring; but, thematter gaining upon him, he found that what he had undertaken not onlyfar exceeded the measure of a letter, but that its importance required rather a more detailed consideration than at that time he had any leisure to bestow upon it. However, having thrown down his first thoughts inthe  form  of  a  letter,  and,  indeed,  when  he  sat  down  to  write,  havingintended it for a private letter, he found it difficult to change the form ofaddress when his sentiments had grown into a greater extent and had received another direction. A different plan, he is sensible, might be more favorable to a commodious division and distribution of his matter.<p>
                    It may not be unnecessary to inform the reader that the following Reflections had their origin in a correspondence between the Author and avery young gentleman at Paris, who did him the honor of desiring his opinion  upon  the  important  transactions  which  then,  and  ever  since,have so much occupied the attention of all men. An answer was written some time in the month of October 1789, but it was kept back uponprudential considerations. That letter is alluded to in the beginning ofthe following sheets. It has been since forwarded to the person to whom it was addressed. The reasons for the delay in sending it were assigned in a short letter to the same gentleman. This produced on his part a new and pressing application for the Author’s sentiments.<p>
                    The Author began a second and more full discussion on the subject.This he had some thoughts of publishing early in the last spring; but, thematter gaining upon him, he found that what he had undertaken not onlyfar exceeded the measure of a letter, but that its importance required rather a more detailed consideration than at that time he had any leisure to bestow upon it. However, having thrown down his first thoughts inthe  form  of  a  letter,  and,  indeed,  when  he  sat  down  to  write,  havingintended it for a private letter, he found it difficult to change the form ofaddress when his sentiments had grown into a greater extent and had received another direction. A different plan, he is sensible, might be more favorable to a commodious division and distribution of his matter.<p>
                </div>           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hum… did you check with fiddle the expected behaviour as described in my post?

Answer (score 1):

In that case just give max width to the wrapper container

```
#centredArea {
            background-color: red;
            max-width: 600px;
            width:100%;
            margin: auto;
            min-height: 2000px;
            text-align: right;
}

#container {
           width: 100%;
            padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: hum… did you check with fiddle the expected behaviour as described in my post?

Comment: Yes I have sir.